# How can I bind a model object using Controller.TryUpdateModel<TModel> Method (TModel, String, String[], String[]) to exclude some properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Let's say I've the following model

```
public class MyClass
{
  public type1 Property1 { get; set; }
  public type1 Property2 { get; set; }
  public type1 Property3 { get; set; }
  public type1 Property4 { get; set; }
  public type1 Property5 { get; set; }  
}
```

I would, for instance, like to bind only the first 3 properties. How can I do so Using one of the Overload for TryUpdateModel() like this

```
TryUpdateModel<TModel> Method (TModel, String, String[], String[])
```

**EDIT**

I don't update my model on the action method but rather using an **OnActionExecuting** filter like this:

```
 public class RegistrationController : Controller
{

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var serialized = Request.Form["formViewModel"];
        if (serialized != null)
        {
            formViewModel = (FormViewModel)new MvcSerializer().Deserialize(serialized);
            TryUpdateModel(formViewModel);
        }
        else
            formViewModel = (FormViewModel)TempData["formViewModel"] ?? new FormViewModel();
    }
  //All the action methods are here
 }
```

So, I'd like to exclude some of the properties depending on which action the view is posting back.

Thanks for helping

Comment: But how do you know which class the data in the form needs to map to?  Can you explain what "FormViewModel" is?

Comment: @Mikerennick: sorry I didn't post everything. I'll edit things

Comment: in case you want to see a totally different approach to model binding, you can download here  http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/ an asp.net mvc samples solution, I guess this could help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default MVC model binding, but just include the following above your class:

```
[Bind(Exclude = "Property1,Property2")]
public class MyClass
{
  public type1 Property1 { get; set; }
  public type1 Property2 { get; set; }
  public type1 Property3 { get; set; }
  public type1 Property4 { get; set; }
  public type1 Property5 { get; set; }  
}
```

incidentally, you could also use:

```
[Bind(Include = "Property3,Property4,Property5")]
public class MyClass
{
  public type1 Property1 { get; set; }
  public type1 Property2 { get; set; }
  public type1 Property3 { get; set; }
  public type1 Property4 { get; set; }
  public type1 Property5 { get; set; }  
}
```

ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION...............

You can place the exclude directive in the ActionResult method like so...

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create( [Bind(Exclude="Property1,Property2")] MyClass myClass)
{ 
     your code....
}
```

Comment: it looks like you are applying the include/exclude at the class level. Can you use TryUpdateModel(model, //whatever to exclude)?

Comment: I'll tell you why I want you to use TryUpdateModel. See the edit on my post.